# How to not allow user to submit links? (html form/PHP/javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have an idea for a website and I will be using a form to allow users to submit a text. The problem is that I don't want anyone to register(because I think that my idea is much more fun without registering as more people will use it) and by doing that I'm sure that people will spam the sh** out of my website.

My question is: What's the easiest way to prevent this from happening? It must be a really good way to block html code and any other pattern/tricks(spaces has to be filtered) spammers will use to submit links.. Of course I will use CAPTCHA to stop automated submission, my concern is about people manually submitting links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also moderate submissions or use a spam filtering service. There quite are a few  services out there that have APIs:

[http://akismet.com/](http://akismet.com)

http://mollom.com

[http://antispam.typepad.com](http://antispam.typepad.com/)

Comment: these are plugins for WordPress, etc. I build my own website.

Comment: Correct, those services have plugins for WordPress, but they also have a direct API that you can use in your custom site. Mollom even has a PHP library premade for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

`strip_tags` should work for most cases.  I personally favor using a more comprehensive library to handle user-submitted text.  htmLawed is excellent for this purpose.

http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php

Comment: It looks really complex. Isn't there something easier to work with?

Comment: `strip_tags` is easy.  htmLawed does take a little setting up, but once you have your options in place, it's easy too.  Bottom line is that `strip_tags` is a solution you can use right away, look in to a library if it doesn't do what you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

using simple validation in complex ways can help you do whatever you want. 
Just pass the input through a function to do whatever you want.

```js
function validate(i)
{
  var i = document.getElementById(i).value;
  if($i contins foo)
    {
      disable submit button
    }
}

<input type="text" id='url' onblur="validate(this.id)">
    <input type="submit" >
```